# Getting Google-Cloud Disk Snapshots to Local-Storage (on-premise)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

In google-cloud, the snapshots of Disk (attached to an instance) can be taken through Python APIs. I'm using the same. My requirement is : moving the snapshot taken by google-cloud, to my local storage.

This I think is kind of common use-case. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Hi, Did you achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is saving the snapshot into a bucket trough ssh, and there you can download it or use fuse or cloudberry to sync it locally.

Reference here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

---

In that case I strongly advice you to perform this using Scripts, you can run a script in the VM to backup using a cron. In this script you can run the snapshot and save it in the current project,

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot [DISK_NAME]
```

then create a vm with a startup script.

```
gcloud compute instances create [YOUR_INSTANCE] --scopes storage-ro \
--metadata startup-script-url=gs://bucket/startupscript.sh
```

In this script copy de disk to a bucket

```
gsutil cp [disk] gs://bucket/Snapshots
```

Comment: Hi Nilo_DS,
I'm trying to get this done through Python APIs
I think, the link provides the steps which needs to be done manually.
Also - through python, its not appropriate to go inside the machine, mount something and do something etc

I was thinking of having the snapshot exported into Bucket and then reading from bucket to local-storage..